# How to encrypt Neo4j Database

Tags: neo4j, aes, encryption-symmetric

I would like to encrypt Neo4j Database,

so what I am doing, I used Eclipse to create the Neo4j database {Java API}, and I used AES 128-bit key, to encrypt the nodes' properties,

How can I replace the properties for each node by encrypted ones automatically?

I am looking for something like using Array, but I am not sure, how?

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j doesn't have built-in encryption. This is something you'd need to do on your own, by encrypting/decrypting within your app (and how you accomplish this is really up to you, and a matter of opinion/discussion, which is out of scope here). Also, as [this Neo4j documentation page](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/capabilities-data-security.html) suggests, you may use an encrypted file system.